# How to copy folder from shared drive to c:\program files in c#

Tags: c#

copy directory error and declaration error

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program prg = new Program();
        prg.CopyFolder(@"C:\Temp\_NB\HELI\MRJ", @"C:\Program Files\");

    }
     private static void CopyFolder(string SourceFolder, string targetPath, bool overwriteexistingFiles = true,string fileTypes ="*.*",bool createTargetIfNotexists = true)
    {
        bool ret = false;
        try
        {
            SourceFolder = SourceFolder.TrimEnd('\\', '/'); ;
            targetPath = targetPath.TrimEnd('\\','/');

            if (Directory.Exists(SourceFolder) == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Source folder does not exist.");
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
            else 
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);

                string [] files  = Directory.GetFiles(SourceFolder,fileTypes);
                foreach (string file in files)
                {
                    FileInfo flinfo = new FileInfo(file);
                    flinfo.CopyTo(targetPath + flinfo.Name, overwriteexistingFiles);
                }
                string [] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(SourceFolder);
                foreach (string dir in dirs)
                {
                    DirectoryInfo drinfo = new DirectoryInfo(dir);

                    if (CopyDirectory(dir, targetPath + drinfo.Name, overwriteexistingFiles) == false)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Unable to copy directory: "+dir);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);                
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a new line before the code in the post, formatting is messed up.

Comment: What are the error messages you get?

Comment: Your `copyFolder` method is declared static but you try to call it on an instance variable.

Comment: getting error on the line :                                                                         if (CopyDirectory(dir, targetPath + drinfo.Name, overwriteexistingFiles) == false)                                                                                           Error 2 The name 'CopyDirectory' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Presumably because you don't have a method called `CopyDirectory`. Which certainly doesn't exist in your code above. Presumably it was intended to be a recursive call to `CopyFolder`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
flinfo.CopyTo(Path.Combine(targetPath, flinfo.Name), true);
```

I think this is what you need.

Comment: getting error on the line if (CopyDirectory(dir, targetPath + drinfo.Name, overwriteexistingFiles) == false) Error 1 Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected Error 2 The name 'CopyDirectory' does not exist in the current context

Comment: using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO

Comment: i want to copy a folder with different subfolders and files in shared drive to C:Program files.